# Why does this regex capture the excluded character?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex like this:

```
(?:(\\s| |\\A|^))(?:@)[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}
```

What I am trying to do is find a pattern that starts with an @ and has two or more characters after, however it can't start in the middle of a word.

I'm new to regex but was under the impression ?: matches but then excludes the character however my regex seems to match but include the characters.  Ideally I'd like for "@test" to return "test" and "test@test" to not match at all.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: it looks like your regex itself is fine:  http://rubular.com/r/WWELFh88SY  how are you executing it?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, meaning it allows you to use parenthesis (for things like alternation, etc) without creating a capturing group.  You are looking for [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) most likely.

Comment: Lookarounds is what I needed, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You could use word boundary to specify your condition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "@test";
    String s2 = "test@test";
    String pattern = "\\b@\\w{2,}\\b";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

o/p :

`@test`

```
throws `IllegalStateException` in the second case (s2)..
```

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is incorrect. The difference between `(...)` and `(?:...)` is only that the former also creates a numbered match group which can be referred to with a backreference from within the regex, or as a captured match group from code following the match.

You could change the code to use lookbehinds, but the simple and straightforward fix is to put `([A-Za-z0-9]{2,})` inside regular parentheses, like I have done here, and retrieve the first matched group. (The `@` doesn't need any parentheses around it in this scenario, but the ones you have are harmless.)

Comment: I actually solved this using lookarounds but your answer has explained to me what I was doing wrong which is why I've accepted it :)  My solution was (?<=( |\\s|\\A|^))[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{2,} (probably some errors or useless parts but it does what I need)

Comment: Indeed, `[@]{1}` is better written simply `@` (!)

Answer (score 0):

How about:
\W@[\S]{2}[\S]*

The strings caught by this regular expression needs to be trimmed and remove the first character.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you better need the following one:

```
(?<=(?<!\w)@)\w{2,}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_DN0W83ug6NEcDbx)

Don't forget to escape the backslashes in Java since in a string literal:

```
(?<=(?<!\\w)@)\\w{2,}
```